# Unable to understand the meaning of errors in C language using Turbo C. I've coded this code

Tags: c, turbo-c

This is what I've coded - the exchange of 2 numbers in c language using turbo c. I've tried real hard to google the solution but the explanation is not understandable as I'm a mere beginner. I'm having my internals on 20th and this is what they might ask along with 40 other programs.....

[image: desc]

Comment: Why are you using curly braces for function calls?! (And one might ask why you're using Turbo C, but that's an other story.)

Comment: Instead of pasting an image of your code, paste the actual code.

Comment: @YashSharma [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good place to learn how to ask questions here.

Comment: @ctrl-shift-esc it's dosbox. How do I do it?

Comment: @Yash File->Save as -> something.c. ALT-TAB out of the dos box into windows -> Open File with Notepad, CTRL-C -> SO web site -> CTRL-V. And dont forget to add 4 spaces in front of each line before you paste ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write `printf("please enter");` instead of `printf{"please enter"};`
The same with `scanf`.
When you see `Statement missing ;` error, you definitely have an language error.

Functions take arguments between `()` and `{}` are used for blocks of code. For example:

```
if (1) {
    printf("Printing\n");
    printf("Printing again\n");
}
```

Another thing is, that we assign value to the left side of `=`.

`a = a-b`
`a = a+b`

Your code should be:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main() {
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter two (2) numbers, please\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    a = a+b;    //assign a to the sum of current a and b
    b = a-b;
    a = a-b;
    printf("The numbers a, b after some calculations are: a=%d and b=%d\n", a, b);
}
```

Comment: thank you! Can't upvote cause I don't have 15 reputation points. Also, it's showing illegal use of pointer and l value required

Comment: @YashSharma you can click on a gray tick below my answer. Make sure, your `&`s are exactly where my are. The code works on my computer and here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php

Answer (score 0):

Use parenthesis () instead of braces {} in your functions `printf()` , `scanf()`.

```
printf("please enter 2 nos");
scanf("%d %d" &a,&b);


printf("our exchanged numbers are a = %d" and b=%d" a,b);
```

And you can't assign value to a expression, it will give `lvalue` error. So to remove this error change,
`a-b = a` change it to `a=a-b` and change all the expressions.

Comment: thank you! Can't upvote cause I don't have 15 reputation points. Also, it's showing illegal use of pointer and l value required

Comment: yeah, lvalue because you are assigning a value to a expression. I have mentioned in the ans that as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, but now the result will just go out in a snap! I'm using turbo c btw and I've heard about this problem. Can you help me?

Comment: yeah.... use getche(); function call at the end of your program.

Comment: 'Error getche() should have a prototype'

Comment: you have to include<conio.h> header file for that function.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
int a, i, fact;
printf("enter the number whose factorial is to be found");
scanf("%d" &a);
while(i > 0)
{
i= a -  1;
fact=a * i;
}
printf("The answer is %d", fact);
getche();
}

Comment: They aren't allowing me to ask another question as I have -ve points on this post....
Just leave it... don't try figuring that out

Comment: assign 1 to your fact variable , and change your logic.
  do { 
    i= a; 
    fact=fact * i;
    a--; 
  } while(i > 1);